# Javascript image rotator flickers occasionally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a JS/CSS image rotator that rotates 5 different images on a section of my website, with a fade in/out effect in CSS.

On desktop/laptop, the images rotate perfectly smoothly, although roughly once every loop, the images flicker and jump quickly to the next one.  What is the cause of this?

Source:-

**CSS**

```
@keyframes fadeinout {
0%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
50%   { opacity: 1; }
}

#rotator {
  animation: fadeinout 3s;
}
```

**JS**

```js
function clientRotator(){

  var section = document.getElementById("clients");
  var clientImg = document.createElement("img");
  clientImg.setAttribute("id", "rotator");
  section.appendChild(clientImg);
  clientImg.src = "assets/exxon-mobil.png";
  var imgArray = ["assets/shell.png", "assets/bp.png", "assets/talisman.png", "assets/cnr-international.png", "assets/exxon-mobil.png"];

  var delaySeconds = 3;
  var iteration = 0;

  setInterval(function(){

    section.removeChild(clientImg);
    clientImg = document.createElement("img");
    clientImg.setAttribute("id", "rotator");
    section.appendChild(clientImg);
    clientImg.src = imgArray[iteration];
    clientImg.setAttribute("alt", "Oil & Gas - Gas Turbine Overhauls");

    if (iteration < imgArray.length-1){
      iteration += 1;
    }
    else {
      iteration = 0;
    }
  }, delaySeconds * 1000)

}
```

Comment: It is possible the `setInterval` timer and the CSS timer are losing sync. A different question: why are you recreating the image element within each interval? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: You should consider using `requestAnimationFrame` in place of `setInterval`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: @RandyCasburn I did think that was possible but the CSS animation only gets fired when the JS creates the element, so it shouldn't be.  The only reason I'm re-creating it is to get the CSS fade to work, as it doesn't work with just changing the image source.  I could do the fade in jQuery I guess.

Comment: That is why you should consider adding/removing class names rather than relying on the ID. That change along likely will solve your issue because you would not be recreating the node.

Comment: Take a look at this solution that uses **NO JavaScript** at all. (this is not my work): https://codepen.io/Ahrengot/pen/bKdLC

Comment: @RandyCasburn ah I didn't think to try adding/removing classnames - thanks. The other issue I had was on some older phones, my rotator is super glitchy, but it works fine when I disabled the fade animation after reading that some older phone frameworks don't handle CSS3 well, but I'll give the classname and no-JS approach a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flicker is caused by small desync of the js and css, you can cause the flicker (for testing) by reducing the css animation from 3s to 2s.

To fix it just add to the `#rotator` the property `opacity: 0;`.